Improve a heuristic to solve the MS-RCPSP
I'm currently working on developing a heuristic to tackle the multi-skill resource constrained project scheduling problem (MS-RCPSP). I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions or modifications you may have to enhance the solution quality. I don't know if there is a possibility to integrate local search or maybe use a metaheuristic.

What is MS-RCPSP? Please provide a description of your algorithm, not just undocumented code

I add the article i'm working based on !!

Check this review. There are several papers referenced that could help you to find a good method to solve it. This is also a good paper to check.

It is very hard problem and very limited number of papers can really help.
Probably exact solvers using optional intervals are a way to go with a few thousands of tasks.
